# Accessing database context in a static property

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm accessing a static list on my class in the following way:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<long> myList = new List<long>() { 1,2,3 }
}
```

---

```
using(EfEntities myDbContext = new EfEntities())
{
    var bar = Foo.myList;
}
```

It works, but to make it more data driven I would like to do something like this, while still keeping the property static if possible (psuedo code):

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<long> myList
    {
        get
        {
            return dbContext.SomeTable.Where(x => x == 1).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to make use of the `myDbContext` in the property and pass the data from the database instead of a hard coded list.

Is there any way to make use of the `myDbContext` instance in the property, without instantiating `Foo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just changing it to a method?

```
public class Foo
{
    public static List<long> GetList(EfEntities dbContext)
    {
        return dbContext.SomeTable.Where(x => x == 1).ToList();
    }
}
```

...and to use it;

```
using(EfEntities myDbContext = new EfEntities())
{
    var bar = Foo.GetList(myDbContext);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the best way to solve it. But let's say that I have 10 methods; is there any way to make use of the context without passing it to all 10 methods?

Comment: @Johan You _could_ register the context in `HttpContext.Items` and get it from there inside the property, but doing that in a good way is probably material for a new question if that's what you need. I'd probably create a disposable class that does the register/unregister/dispose for you, and a static method to get the current `EfEntities` context from the `HttpContext` if that makes any sense :)